# Can I play mp4s on my Nexus through usb-on-the-go?

Tags: file-management, usb-on-the-go, samsung-nexus-10, media-files, mp4

I have a male end micro-usb to female USB and I can plug in my USB drive and see all the files using the OTG disk explorer app, and I have a video player app that plays the videos I download to my tablet, but she I try and open the videos on my USB it doesn't work.

Is there a different app I should use or some setting I need to change so that way I can watch the videos without having to move them from my USB to my tablet?

Edit: also, is there a way I can move files between my tablet and USB?

Comment: Which Android version are you using?

Comment: @Firelord 5.1.1 according to the "about" section in settings.